# Link HTML para abrir formulário sem causar refresh na página

Tags: javascript, html

Criei um botão de um formulário, mas ao clicar ele dá refresh na página index onde ele está e não quero isso, não quero que atualize a pagina, somente quero que abra o popup com o formulário, como corrijo?

```
a href="#" onclick="window.open('form.html', 'Pagina', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=YES, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=YES, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=90%, LEFT=280%, WIDTH=485, HEIGHT=545');"><img src='imagens/button-contato.png'></a>
```

Dados do form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="PT-BR">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulário de Contato</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Do not change the code! -->
<a id="foxyform_embed_link_181315" href="http://br.foxyform.com/">foxyform</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, t){
        var g = d.createElement(t),
                s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src = "http://br.foxyform.com/js.php?id=181315&sec_hash=e727220c0f2&width=445px&heigth=525px";
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
    }(document, "script"));
</script>
<!-- Do not change the code! -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: você quer que a pagina não de refresh, e faça oque ?

Comment: Tente usar um "event.preventDefault() seguido por return false" no final do onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mude o `href` para `javascript:void(0)`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('form.html', 'Pagina', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=YES, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=YES, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=90%, LEFT=280%, WIDTH=485, HEIGHT=545');"><img src='imagens/button-contato.png'></a>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeito parceiro, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tive que alterar a parte do script que não estava pegando os dados do formulário e sim o script que gera o formulário. Então seguem as alterações que funcionaram.

Altere a tag  para não chamar uma outra página e sim a função:

```
<a id="foxyform_embed_link_181315" href="#" onClick="abrirForm(document)">foxyform</a>
```

altere a parte do script para nomear a função:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function abrirForm(d){
           var l = d.getElementById("foxyform_embed_link_181315");
      i = d.createElement('IFRAME');
  i.src = "http://br.foxyform.com/form.php?id=181315&sec_hash=e727220c0f2";
  i.width = "445px";
  i.height = "524px";
  i.frameborder = 0;
  i.setAttribute('style', 'border: none;');
  i.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
  l.setAttribute('style', 'display: block; width: 445px; font-size: 0.7em; color: grey; text-align: right; text-decoration: none;');
  l.parentNode.insertBefore(i,l);
}(document);

</script >
```

Formulário carregado
[image: formulário teste carregado]

Comment: Não funcionou, parou o refresh mas a pagina ainda rola para o inicio, e não abre o popup.

Comment: Sou iniciante ainda em javascript, não entendo muito bem eu preciso que ao clicar no botão abre uma janela popup para o cliente enviar os seus dados caso se interesse pelo produto, então o cliente clica no botao e abre a janela onde irá inserir seus dados, e se fosse possível queria que o codigo pegasse o nome do produto que ele se interessou, pois irei colocar um botão em cada produto, como se fosse um botão de pgto, mas como são maquinas caras e precisa de modificações pra cada cliente, não tem como colocar direto um botão de pgto. Preciso que ele me envie os dados e pra entrar em contato.

Comment: Eu havia inserido esse codigo para o popup

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
        var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
        var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
        var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=40%' + top + ', left=' + left);
    }

    </script>

Comment: A solução do nosso amigo Dvdsamm funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Agora se eu quiser que ao clicar no botão pra preencher o formulário o código pegue qual produto o cliente se interessou, pois vai ter um botão pra cada item, qdo o cliente clicar no botão que na imagem esta como contato seja informado no formulario qual item ele se interessou, onde estão as flechas, tem como fazer sem php, não estudei ainda, segue print do site que estou fazendo http://prntscr.com/ghgf8p

Answer (score 0):

Quando você acionar um elemento , o browser pressupõe que você deseja seguir para um novo endereço. Como você atribuiu "#" ao href do elemento, ele carrega novamente a página, adicionando "#" ao final da url.

Você vai precisar executar o script assim: